# Draw on large UIView take a lot of memory

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

when I start to draw on large UIView ( width: 3700 , height: 40000 ), it takes a lot of memory
when app starts, memory is 150 MB and when start drawing on it( calling `setNeedsDisplay` method) take around 1 GB and app is gonna crash

```
class DrawingVc: UIViewController {

    let  contentView = DrawableView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.view.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:view.frame.width,  height: 
        view.frame.height * 50)
 }
```

here is the code of custom view, as you can see, `setNeedsDisplay` runs on `touchMoves`

```
 class DrawableView: UIView {

    var mLastPath: UIBezierPath?
    weak var scdelegate: DrawableViewDelegate?
    var isDrawEnable = true

    private var drawingLines : [UIBezierPath] = []

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        debugPrint("request draw")

        drawLine()

    }

    private func drawLine() {

        UIColor.blue.setStroke()
        for line in drawingList {
            line.lineWidth = 4
            line.stroke()
            line.lineCapStyle = .round
        }


    }

    var drawingList = [UIBezierPath]()
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if touches.count == 2 {
            return
        }

        let location = (touches.first?.location(in: self))!
        mLastPath = UIBezierPath()
        mLastPath?.move(to: location)
        prevPoint = location

        drawingList.append(mLastPath!)
    }

        var prevPoint: CGPoint?
      var isFirst = true
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        debugPrint("touchesMoved: " , (touches.first?.location(in: self).x)!  , (touches.first?.location(in: self).y)! )
        if let coalescedtouches =  event?.coalescedTouches(for: touches.first!)
        {
            for coalescedTouch in coalescedtouches
            {
                let locationInView = coalescedTouch.location(in: self)

                if let prevPoint = prevPoint {
                    let midPoint = CGPoint( x: (locationInView.x   + prevPoint.x) / 2, y: (locationInView.y + prevPoint.y) / 2)
                    if isFirst {
                        mLastPath?.addLine(to: midPoint)
                    }else {

                        mLastPath?.addQuadCurve(to: midPoint, controlPoint: prevPoint)
                    }
                    isFirst = false
                } else {
                    mLastPath?.move(to: locationInView)

                }
                prevPoint = locationInView
            }

        }
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }



}
```

What makes this problem and how that fix?

Comment: Would it be feasible to calculate which part of the drawing is visible, then adapt the drawing calls to only draw that part, and redraw when the visible part has changed?

Answer (score 4):

Your view is larger than the largest possible screen on an iOS device, so I suppose your view is embedded in a scrollview. You should only draw the visible parts of your view. Unfortunately, this is not supported by `UIView` directly. You may take a look on [CATiledLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catiledlayer), which supports drawing of only visible parts of a layer, and it supports different levels of details for zoomed layers, too.

Comment: Tnx body, it's help a lot... I really appreciate it.